# Traversal Filter in Graphical Query parser Solr

Tags: solr

I am using graphical query parser that was introduced in Solr 6. On the traversal filter, i have provided conditions on one of the field and it is working fine. But i was not able to provide conditions on multiple fields.

Please find the below query.

Working -

```
     {!graph from=HIERARCHY_LEVEL_PARENT_KEY to=HIERARCHY_LEVEL_KEY
    traversalFilter=HIERARCHY_ID:2000001}(HIERARCHY_ID:2000001 AND 
(HIERARCHY_LEVEL_KEY:451 OR  HIERARCHY_LEVEL_KEY:59734))
```

Not working -

```
  {!graph from=HIERARCHY_LEVEL_PARENT_KEY to=HIERARCHY_LEVEL_KEY 
 traversalFilter=HIERARCHY_ID:2000001 OR DWH_COLUMN_NAME:P1_NO}
(HIERARCHY_ID:2000001 AND (HIERARCHY_LEVEL_KEY:451 OR  HIERARCHY_LEVEL_KEY:59734))
```

Answer (score 1):

`traversalFilter="(HIERARCHY_ID:2000001) OR (DWH_COLUMN_NAME:P1_NO)"` Works for me.

I have a follow up question with a problem i have that relates if you or anybody else could help.

Im trying to fomulate a query like this `traversalFilter="(-field:x) OR (field2:y)"`

Meaning, if field does not have value x it is ok, if field has value x and field2 has y its also ok. Other cases is filtered away.